# Problema al insertar en la base de datos

Tags: php, html, mysql

He intentado almacenar valores en mi base de datos y me he topado con un problema de manera constante ya que no puedo insertar uno de los valores y no entiendo el por qué, el atributo está bien definido tanto en html como en php, pero aun así no doy con el error.

Este sería el Código HTML:

```
    <h3>Datos del Representante</h3>
    <label>Tipo de Cedula del Representante</label>
    <select name="tipoCedulaRepresentantes">
        <option value="venezolana">Venezolana</option>
        <option value="extrangera">Extrangera</option>
    </select>
    <br><br>

    <label>Numero de Cedula del Representante</label>
    <input type="text" name="cedulaRepresentante" id="cedulaRepresentante"><br><br>

    <label>Apellidos del Representante</label>
    <input type="text" name="primerApellidoRepresentante" id="primerApellidoRepresentante" placeholder="Primer Apellido">
    <input type="text" name="segundoApellidoRepresentante" id="segundoApellidoRepresentante" placeholder="Segundo Apellido"><br><br>

    <label>Nombres del Representante</label>
    <input type="text" name="primerNombreRepresentante" id="primerNombreRepresentante" placeholder="Primer Nombre">
    <input type="text" name="segundoNombreRepresentante" id="segundoNombreRepresentante" placeholder="Segundo Nombre"><br><br>

    <label>Edad Representante</label> 
    <select name="edadRepresentante">
    <?php
    for ($i=18; $i <101 ; $i++) { 
        echo "<option  value=$i>$i</option>";
    }
    ?>
    </select><br><br>

    <label>Direccion del Representante</label>
    <input type="text" name="direccionRepresentante" maxlength="100" id="direccionRepresentante"><br><br>

    <label>Telefono del Representante</label>
    <input type="number" name="codigoTelefonoRepresentante" id="codigoTelefonoRepresentante" placeholder="Codigo">
    <input type="number" name="telefonoRepresentante" id="telefonoRepresentante" placeholder="Numero"><br><br>

    <label>Correo del Representante</label>
    <input type="mail" name="correoRepresentante" id="correoRepresentante"><br><br>

    <label>Profesion del Representante</label>
    <select name="profesionRepresentante" id="profesionRepresentante">
        <?php
        include "conexion.php";
        $sql = "select id_profesion, profesion from profesiones order by profesion";
        $registros = mysqli_query($conexion, $sql);

        while ($reg = mysqli_fetch_array($registros)) {
            echo "<option value=$reg[0]>$reg[1]</option>";
        }
        mysqli_close($conexion);
        ?>
    </select><br><br>

    <label>Direccion del Trabajo del Representante</label>
    <input type="text" name="direccionTrabajoRepresentante" id="direccionTrabajoRepresentante"><br><br>

    <label>Telefono del Trabajo del Representante</label>
    <input type="number" name="codigoTelefonoTrabajoRepresentante" id="codigoTelefonoTrabajoRepresentante" placeholder="Codigo">
    <input type="number" name="telefonoTrabajoRepresentante" id="telefonoTrabajoRepresentante" placeholder="Numero"><br><br>

    <label>Parentesco del Representante</label>
    <select name="parentescoRepresentante" id="parentescoRepresentante">
        <?php
        include "conexion.php";
        $sql="select  id_parentesco, parentesco from parentescos";
        $registros = mysqli_query($conexion,$sql);

        while ($reg = mysqli_fetch_array($registros)) {
            echo "<option value=$reg[0]>$reg[1]</option>";
        }
        mysqli_close($conexion);
        ?>
    </select><br><br>

    <label>Direccion de Emergencia</label>
    <input type="text" name="direccionEmergencia" id="direccionEmergencia"><br><br><hr>

    <!--Datos de los Padres-->

    <h3>Datos de los Padres o Madre</h3>
    <label>Tipo de Cedula del Padre o Madre</label>
    <select name="tipoCedulaPadres">
        <option value="venezolana">Venezolana</option>
        <option value="extrangera">Extrangera</option>
    </select>
    <br><br>

    <label>Numero de Cedula del Padre o Madre</label>
    <input type="text" name="cedulaPadres" id="cedulaPadres"><br><br>

    <label>Apellidos del Padre o Madre</label>
    <input type="text" name="primerApellidoPadres" id="primerApellidoPadres" placeholder="Primer Apellido">
    <input type="text" name="segundoApellidoPadres" id="segundoApellidoPadres" placeholder="Segundo Apellido"><br><br>

    <label>Nombres del Padre o Madre</label>
    <input type="text" name="primerNombrePadres" id="primerNombrePadres" placeholder="Primer Nombre">
    <input type="text" name="segundoNombrePadres" id="segundoNombrePadres" placeholder="Segundo Nombre"><br><br>

    <label>Direccion del Padre o Madre</label>
    <input type="text" name="direccionPadres" id="direccionPadres"><br><br>

    <label>Telefono del Padre o Madre</label>
    <input type="number" name="codigoTelefonoPadres" id="codigoTelefonoPadres" placeholder="Codigo">
    <input type="number" name="telefonoPadres" id="telefonoPadres" placeholder="Numero"><br><br><hr>
```

Este seria la sentencia en PHP que me conecta con la base de datos:

```
    $registroRepresentante = "insert into representantes (tipoCedulaRepresentante, cedulaRepresentante, primerApellidoRepresentante, segundoApellidoRepresentante, primerNombreRepresentante, segundoNombreRepresentante, edadRepresentante, direccionRepresentante, codigoTelefonoRepresentante, telefonoRepresentante, correoRepresentante, direccionTrabajoRepresentante, codigoTelefonoTrabajoRepresentante, telefonoTrabajoRepresentante, direccionEmergencia, fk_parentesco, fk_profesion) values (
    '$_POST[tipoCedulaRepresentantes]','$_POST[cedulaRepresentante]','$_POST[primerApellidoRepresentante]',
    '$_POST[segundoApellidoRepresentante]','$_POST[primerNombreRepresentante]','$_POST[segundoNombreRepresentante]',
    $_POST[edadRepresentante],'$_POST[direccionRepresentante]','$_POST[codigoTelefonoRepresentante]',
    '$_POST[telefonoRepresentante]','$_POST[correoRepresentante]','$_POST[direccionTrabajoRepresentante]',
    '$_POST[codigoTelefonoTrabajoRepresentante]','$_POST[telefonoTrabajoRepresentante]','$_POST[direccionEmergencia]',
    '$_POST[parentescoRepresentante]','$_POST[profesionRepresentante]')";

    $registrarRepresentante = mysqli_query($conexion,$registroRepresentante) or die ("Problemas en el query".mysqli_error($conexion));
    echo "ingresaron datos representantes";


$registroPadres =  "insert into padres (tipoCedulaPadre, cedulaPadre, primerApellidoPadre, segundoApellidoPadre, primerNombrePadre, segundoNombrePadre, direccionPadre, codigoTelefonoPadre, telefonoPadre) values ('$_POST[tipoCedulaPadres]','$_POST[cedulaPadres]',
    '$_POST[primerApellidoPadres]','$_POST[segundoApellidoPadres]','$_POST[primerNombrePadres]','$_POST[segundoNombrePadres]',
    '$_POST[direccionPadres]','$_POST[codigoTelefonoPadres]','$_POST[telefonoPadres]') ";

$registrarPadres = mysqli_query($conexion,$registroPadres) or die ("Problemas en el query".mysqli_error($conexion));
echo "ingresaron datos padres";
```

Lo que no entiendo es el por que me arroja el siguiente error:
[image: Imagen con error]

Comment: Aunque no tenga que ver con el problema, fijate que en esta línea `<option value="extrangera">Extrangera</option>` la palabra debería ser "Extranjera", con "j". Un detalle nada más.

Comment: Listo, muchas gracias.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

estas escribiendo mal

en algunos lugares pones `tipoCedulaRepresentantes`

deberia ser `tipoCedulaRepresentante`

veo que aqui es el error

```
'$_POST[tipoCedulaRepresentantes]'
```

debe ser

```
'$_POST[tipoCedulaRepresentante]'
```

Comment: Listo allí tenia el error, muchas gracias de verdad, imagino que he visto tanto código que estaba abollado con una tontería, de verdad mil gracias.

Comment: Si me sirve y no me faltan las comillas, recuerda que al pedir el valor por el método post o get las comillas van por fuera por qué debes agregar todo el atributo incluyendo la variable global post o get. Esto solo en el caso de los string o date

Comment: @aldanux exacto.

Comment: Lo que acaba de decir, si no le colocó las comillas no me arrastra el error, pero tampoco me realiza la inserción de los datos en la base de datos.

Comment: Por qué no es un problema de comillas, es que estaba mal escrito el atributo al que estaba llamando, es decir coloque una "s" de más. Y es lo que el colocó.

Comment: Como guste, saludos.

Answer (score 1):

Según tengo entendido, deberías poner de esta forma el POST

```
'$_POST['tipoCedulaRepresentantes']'
```

De lo contrario te lo toma como una constante.

Comment: +1 - Seria bueno si demostraras como se concatena bien con las comillas a pasarlo a una variable y avisarle que esta en peligro a ataques de inyecciones SQL... Saludos

Comment: @aldanux es verdad. Buen punto a tener en cuenta. Por otro lado si fuera por mi, nunca pondria en la vista, el modelo.

Comment: Pero eso ya no implica al funcionamiento, ni la seguridad... simplemente es un patrón de diseño

Answer (score 0):

Me parece que se te paso una 's' y debe ser :

```
'$_POST[tipoCedulaRepresentante]'
```